# iPad Air 5th Gen gets massively hot while using ANY notetaking app and Apple Pencil 2

Tags: ipad, battery, notes.app, apple-pencil, onenote

iPad Air 5th gen gets massively hot and drains battery, when using just any note taking app and Apple Pencil.
Even if I do not have any Note taking app active, when I just attach the Pencil to the side (connected to iPad), the iPad gets very hot and drains battery.
Is this normal for iPad?

Comment: Has this always happened? When did you last update the iPad?

Comment: @IconDaemon iPadOS 16.1.1 - very recently. The moment I connect Pencil, iPad heats up

Comment: Was it heating up _before_ the update?

Comment: It used to heat as normal. But, not so much that the charging would stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question "is this normal" is most likely yes. iPads have no active cooling. I have been using Notability and Goodnotes and found that no matter which App I use for notes, I have been experiencing high temps due to high screen brightness. If you also charge at the same time you produce even more heat. Therefore, ideally you use a lower screen brightness (something closer to 50% or even less) and don't charge while using those apps. This helped in my case using the previous iPad Air.

Edit:
Given your more detailed usage description I don't think this is normal. I have never seen my battery drain completely within 60 minutes. Also, I have never experienced that the iPad does not charge due to heat. Maybe go to the next Apple Store and check with them what you should do.

Comment: No. I don't charge my iPad while taking notes. However, when I use Apple Pencil (connected with Bluetooth), WiFi and use any note taking app, the iPad heats up so much that the battery drains like within 45-60 minutes. And once the battery drops, I switch off Bluetooth and WiFi, and put it on charging mode. The charging stops until the iPad cools down - it gets heated so much.