# Ipad Air gets so hot in Notes app

Tags: ipad, notes.app, apple-pencil

My iPad Air 5th usually gets very hot while drawing in the Notes app with pencil. Is it normal and if any workaround? A related [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/450348) here only has a very vague answer, from which it is still unclear whether it is normal. Also are some other threads on the internet, [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253831014) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/iPadPro/comments/wsh0wj/ipad_heating_up_during_handwriting_in_apple_notes/), not clear either.